# twgl.setUniforms analog call in native webgl

Tags: webgl, twgl.js

I dont use twgl i wanna pure webgl to set uniforms for "gl.createTexture()".

Source Code:

```js
  const depthTexture = gl.createTexture();
  ...

    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_projectedTexture: depthTexture
    }
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twgl.setUniforms()` is equivalent to a combo of WebGL functions to bind the texture and set the uniforms. The scheme is:

```
const tex = gl.createTexture();
//...

// Bind the texture
gl.activeTexture(...);
gl.bindTexture(...);
gl.uniform1i(...); // for the texture

/*
* Set the uniforms -- For each uniform, depending
* on its type, a call of a corresponding function
* from the 'uniform' function group
*/ 
gl.uniform<...>(...);
//...
```

A more extensive example of how to translate `setUniforms()` into native WebGL can be found in the TWGL documentation of [setUniforms()](https://twgljs.org/docs/module-twgl.html#.setUniforms). An overview of all WebGL functions, including the `uniform` variants, can be found in the official [WebGL 2.0 API Quick Reference Guide](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl20-reference-guide.pdf).

Comment: Ok it is classic ` gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);` . Thanks for assist!